# How pass Arraylist to another class

Tags: java, arraylist

Hello I'm a beginner in Java and this is my question: I have this first class with the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class A {

    ArrayList<String> a1;

    public A (ArrayList<String> a1) {
        this.a1 = a1;
        a1.add("Winter");
        a1.add("Spring");
        a1.add("Summer");
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getString() {
        return a1;
    }

}
```

second class with the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class B {

    ArrayList<String> b1;

    public void A (ArrayList<String> b1) {
        this.b1 = b1;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getString() {
        b1.addAll(a1);
        return b1;
    }

}
```

and third class with code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class C {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> j1 = new ArrayList<String>();

        A a1 = new A(j1);
        B b1 = new B();

        System.out.println(a1.getString());
        System.out.println(b1.getString());
    }
}
```

How to pass arraylist from class A to class B?

Comment: You don't need to pass it from A to B : your list is `j1` , let `A` modify it, then pass it to `B` (e.g `b1.A(j1)`) . Note that the name of the `A` method in `B` is a bit misleading, and that by convention a method name should start with a lower-case letter.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want `b1.getString()` to recieve `a1`s array.

First of all: you should really change the names of methods and variables in your code so it's less misleading, as Amaud suggests in your comments.

Second: you need a *way in* to the method to be able to pass it stuff.

See the changes below (I'm keeping the names so it's similar to your code, but I insist, you should change them):

**class A** *(stays the same, just including it for completion sake)*

```
public class A {
    ArrayList<String> a1;

    public A (ArrayList<String> a1) {
        this.a1 = a1;
        a1.add("Winter");
        a1.add("Spring");
        a1.add("Summer");
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getString() {
        return a1;
    }
}
```

**Class B** *Added the parameter in getString*

```
public class B {
    ArrayList<String> b1;

    public void A (ArrayList<String> b1) {
        this.b1 = b1;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getString(ArrayList<String> a1) {
        b1.addAll(a1);
        return b1;
    }
}
```

**Class C**

```
public class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> j1 = new ArrayList<String>();

        A a1 = new A(j1);
        B b1 = new B();

        System.out.println(a1.getString());
        System.out.println(b1.getString(a1.getString()));
    }
}
```

There is also the option of just passing `j1` instead of `a1.getString()` on the last line, since they would be the same in this example. It would look like:

```
        System.out.println(b1.getString(j1));
```